# Unemployment eligibility for U.S. citizen working overseas for California based company

Tags: united-states, california, working-abroad, unemployment

I received word I will be getting laid off at the end of the year. I currently work overseas for a California based company. I am a U.S. citizen and will be returning to CA (my home state) due to being laid off. Will I have any problems applying for unemployment due to being/working overseas?

Comment: Has your employer been paying unemployment taxes?

Answer (score 2):

You are “currently” working outside the USA -it depends on how long “currently” is. For example, if you moved to Germany to install things or train people for a month, you would be treated like someone working in the USA, and it doesn’t matter that you were laid off while in Germany.

If you stay long enough in Germany, Germany will decide that you have to pay taxes in Germany, and German employment law will apply - which will be of advantage to you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, unemployment benefits are given based on wages earned in a state.
You can contact the [California Employment Development Department](https://www.edd.ca.gov/Unemployment/) about your situation. It doesn't sound like you will be eligible, but you should contact them to be sure.

Comment: When you say earned in a state, do you mean physically there? I have a W2 with income earned and have paid state and federal taxes. The only difference really was my location being overseas similar to remote work.

Comment: I believe that it's usually based on your work location, I'm not sure how CA has interpreted this for remote work.

Answer (score 0):

See if you qualify for unemployment in all places where you have worked. If you worked in California within the last couple of years, check your eligibility with [EDD](https://edd.ca.gov/en/Unemployment/Eligibility).

Do the same with the locality/country where you now work. You may be eligible in one, both, or neither.